# css: how to draw circle with text beside it

Tags: css, sass

I want to know how to draw a circle around only two letter in a logo using CSS.

Please check the attached picture[image: I wand do the same]

Here's the code I used, but it didn't work

```css
.badge {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #337EFB;
  padding:-5px;
}
```

```html
<span><a class="badge" href="/">fb</span><span>keeper</span></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the display of the `.badge` to `inline-block`, and use `line-height` to center the text vertically.

Note: to make the entire title clickable replace the outer span with an a tag, and convert the one on the inside to a span tag.

```css
.title {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--title-color);
  --title-color: #337EFB;
}

.badge {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--title-color);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a class="title" href="#">
  <span class="badge" href="/">fb</span>
  <span>keeper</span>
</a>
```

Comment: that's great, but "keeper" is not clickable.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention that. Update it.

Answer (score 1):

You have not closed your anchor tag correctly. You need to close it before your second span for word keeper start and inside a first span, Please look into below code and try once:

`<span><a class="badge" href="/">fb</a></span><span>keeper</span>`

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem in your html code. Here is what you should put :)

```html
<a href="/"><span class="badge">fb</span><span>keeper</span></a>
```